# How do I redirect thousands of WordPress URLs to a subdirectory?

Tags: seo, domains, htaccess, wordpress

I have a WordPress website and it has almost 22,000 blog posts.  It has been running with good SEO for the past 6 years.  The contents are scattered in almost all social media and backlinked in a lot of websites.  I also have data in Google Analytics  that I would like to preserve.

I'm planning to start a fresh news aggregator site at the base directory of the domain. I want to move the old blog contents to the subdirectory i.e. `/blog`.  I want to run the same old blog in it without affecting the SEO.

I tried implementing 301 redirects in *.htaccess*, but they are not working the way I want. This is my blog URL pattern `/2015/01/10/post-title/` and I tried with this 301 redirection code in *.htaccess*:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/blog
```

However,  it is redirecting all URLs of the aggregator site which I'm currently running under www directory.

Comment: Hey I hope you gonna redirect entire blog URLs to subfolder and also you gonna come up with new site in home directory in that case / 301 won't work, You have to manually redirect all the URLs to subfolder.

Comment: @gokulkarthick Not necessarily, providing the new URLs in the root don't also follow the same "blog" URL pattern: `/2015/01/10/post-title/`.

Answer (score 1):

> This is my blog URL pattern `/2015/01/10/post-title/`

You need to specifically check for the *old* URL pattern, otherwise you will naturally redirect *everything*, including all the new URLs of the "news aggregator site".

Try, something like the following instead, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d/[\w-]+/$ /blog/$0 [R=301,L]
```

This specifically checks for URLs of the form `/2015/01/10/post-title/` and 301 redirects to `/blog/2015/01/10/post-title/`.

`$0` is a backreference that contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.